# Can I make this if statement with lots of ORs more concise?

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm refreshing my knowledge of C by doing some random exercises. The following is an excerpt from my solution to counting how many vowels in a string. It works but there has to be a more concise way to write this if statement. Any ideas?

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if(input[i] == 'a' || input[i] == 'e' || input[i] == 'i' || input[i] == 'o' || input[i] == 'u') {
        total++;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html

Comment: If you are only inerested in ASCII encoding, directly indexing a 128-byte lookup table with the char value would be reasonably quick, and really flexible, with lower/upper case handled easily.  With a bit(!) of shifting etc. a 128-bit table could do the same job and would fit into a cache line.

Comment: @MartinJames Each byte can hold the value (0/1) for 8 characters. 128 / 8 = 16 bytes. Would easily fit in most cache lines. Nice solution! Even with two values in each byte, the table would fit in a 64 byte cache line.

Comment: @Carcigenicate That is the problem. C does not have builtin sets. You might simulate with large bitfields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with a `switch` with fallthrough cases:

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    switch (input[i]) {
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
        total++;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point. I feel mine is more readable but maybe that's because I don't really like using switch statements :P

Comment: @Shmink use switch wherever you can. The compiler decides what is the most efficient lowering for it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the library function `strtok` to tokenize the input string, like this:

```
pch = strtok (input,"aeiou");
while (pch != NULL)
{
    total++;
    pch = strtok (NULL, "aeiou");
}
```

Note that strtok is destructive to the input string.

Answer (score 1):

**strchr** lets you search a character string for a specific character.  It looks like a reasonable way to solve your problem.

Untested code:

```
char findMe = 'e';
char *vowels="aeiou";
if (strchr(vowels, findMe) != NULL)
{
   print("found\n");
}
else
{
   print("not found");
}
```

Comment: How is this remotely related to what OP is asking? He needs the count of all the vowels in the input string. Boolean on whether a vowel exists doesn't help in anyway. Moreover he is trying to make his condition more succinct. Adding more conditions in your code to search for all the vowels in just going to make the condition even larger.

Answer (score 0):

you can make it this way better and faster 
make array of the variables you want to check 
Ex char  *array = ['i','o','a','e'];
then

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   for(int i2 = 0; i2 < length; i2++){
      if(input[i] == array[i2]){
         total++;
      }
  }
}
```

this way you can add as much as char you want to compare and less || statements and faster .

Comment: True, I was considering this approach. Out of curiosity, not that it matters at these small scales but what's better for performance between a bigger if statement or a nested if statement?

Comment: I agree. The OP code will overcome this solution as the string grows. Not only does the OP's example run in linear time, but the OR statements will short-circuit avoiding unnecessary checks compared to this O(n^2) approach.

Comment: @Shmink I think the nesting loop will make it more obscure.

Comment: in my opinion : nested is better for reading , since it all depends on your starting condition for example I want to check if this char equal to( i )and (i) condition I put it in the last if condition block or in the last line among the conditions that way will take approximate the  same time

Comment: Readability really falls under opinion. As for your comment on the "same time," I'm not sure if I understand what you mean? In the worst case, the vowel array will have to be iterated for each character of the string, and even when a character is matched, it will still have to keep searching the vowel array causing unnecessary checks.

Comment: what I was meaning is it depends on your conditions order , but I get more good solution for  which will increase the performance and will save you unnecessary checks  you know that every char have asci number right what if we order each char in our array in ascendant order according to his asci number , now we have a array of asci numbers let's say it's ['66','77','88','99'] then we take the input transform it to asci number and check right in the center of the array if equal then you got your answer if not  see if it's bigger or smaller if bigger move to the right side and use it as new arr

Comment: use it as a new array to it's center again , and if low go to the left side and do the same ,  let's say my input after transformation is 77 so I'll start with the half length of the array which is it's value is 77 ,second try my input is 99 ,I'll go to the half which is 1 equal to 77 no mu number is 99 it should be next element and so on . that used in tree algorithm and tree is a data structure .

Comment: *you can make it this way better and faster* - faster? you sure about that? Array accesses are always going to lead to dereference. It is much more efficient comparing against constant values. Not to mention the looping overheading (but I guess any decent  compiler would unroll it).

Comment: `char *array = ['i','o','a','e'];` is not even valid C code. `length` is the wrong limit for inner loop.

Comment: A binary search for each element in the array still grows quicker asymptotically compared to a linear search. And with a binary search, it still becomes shadowed by the nested loop => O(n^2 + nlog(n)) >= O(n). If instead one loop where to be used, it still doesn't achieve the speed of linear, O(nlogn) >= O(n)